# Linear Regression with Neural Net with betas as output

Tags: neural-networks

In a linear regression of multiple variables,
$$
y = X\beta^T + \epsilon
$$,
where $X$ and $y$ are the independent and dependent variables, we can estimate OLS $\beta$ as follows:
$$
\hat \beta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y
$$

I wonder if it is possible to design a neural network such that given $X$ and $y$ (with a variable number of rows) as input, it will output $\hat \beta$.

Comment: You mean, you want a neural network to learn to approximate the solution operator mapping $(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})\to\mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{y}$? I don't see why not, so long as $(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})$ are of consistent shape. If not, this does get harder, as we need a neural net capable of handling variable length (and non-sequence) inputs, which is nonstandard.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I mean the rows of $X$ and $y$ are variable depending on different inputs.  I edited the question. Yes, it is about learning the mapping $(X, y) \to X^+y$.

Comment: I have had trouble getting neural nets to work with variable length input *vectors* as inputs (of course there's much work on variable sequences) to work; I hope someone else here has interesting advice to share with us on this matter.

Comment: So you want the neural network to find the $\beta$ parameters? Why? It's like building an artificially intelligent robot to build you a hammer. You can simply use OLS for that for a much simpler and more robust solution.

Comment: This is a component of a larger neural net that I am trying to build, in which $X$ and $y$ are embeddings from other parts of the net.

Comment: Then could you give us more details? Please edit to describe what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Let me think about how to put it clearly as it mostly involves application details that are not relevant. To build it as part of NN is to make it possible to do things end-to-end.

Comment: The “neural network” that does this is a single vector and a single bias with no activations and MSE loss. In other words, it is identically a regression — but using backprop and gradient descent to solve it will be slow, inefficient and imprecise.

Comment: @Sycorax that is the neural network that solves a given linear regression problem, not the neural network that maps $(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})\to\hat\beta$ (notice that this mapping is nonlinear); i.e. we are interested here in approximating the least squares solution *operator*, not a given least squares problem.

Comment: @Tim If I understand correctly, one could imagine an approach like this to be useful in solving a sequence of related and large least squares problems (where direct least squares computation is difficult).

Comment: @JohnMadden Then you don’t even need weights or biases — just pseudo inverse and multiplication.

Comment: I think theoretically one could just do that. Pseudo inverse and multiplication are differentiable operations and the gradient just flows through. But it is probably going to be very slow if one puts pinv in the middle of a network.

Comment: Why do you need gradient updates *at all*? The "neural network" is simply directly computing $\hat \beta$ using matrix arithmetic. One example is to compute the SVD $X = USV^T$ and then $\hat \beta = V S^{-1} U^Ty$. This question reads like an XY Problem -- what problem are you trying to solve, and why is a neural network an essential part of computing the regression coefficients?

Comment: Yes, it by itself doesn't even have any learnable parameters. It is because this is a component of a bigger network. The input and output are embeddings from/to other parts of the network. I think one alternative to `pinv` is that I freeze the other weights and change $\beta$ to minimize some least squares. Then freeze $\beta$ and update the other weights. I optimize the two things in alternation.

Comment: It sounds like [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244433). Tell us what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve. Why do you think you need it? Please edit your question for more details, otherwise, it's not possible to answer it because we would have to make many guesses on what you mean.

Comment: yes you definitely can, at the end of the day the NN will just approximate the closed form of the OLS, nothing too crazy... you will find this under topics like meta learning and hypernetworks